why never Frame.Close received from websocketSession.incoming in ktor?
This is my test function:
fun testGetWebsocketCloseCode() = runBlocking {
        val path = "ws"
        val code: Short = 3000
        val message = "CustomError"
        val server = embeddedServer(Netty, 0, LOCAL_HOST) {
            install(io.ktor.server.websocket.WebSockets)
            routing {
                webSocket("/$path") {
                    delay(500)
                    this.close(CloseReason(code, message))
                }
            }
        }
        server.start(wait = false)
        val client = HttpClient(CIO) {
            install(WebSockets)
        }

        val listenPort = server.resolvedConnectors().first().port
        val url = "ws://$LOCAL_HOST:$listenPort/$path"
        println("connecting url: $url")

        val session = client.webSocketSession(url)
        for (frame in session.incoming) {
            println("received frame: $frame")
        }
        val closeReason = session.closeReason.await()
        println("disconnect: $closeReason")

        assertEquals(code, closeReason?.code)
        assertEquals(message, closeReason?.message)

        server.stop()
        println("server stopped")
    }

println never print received frame. How can I get the Frame.Close frame?
